# responseXML.xml is not an object

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services, spservices

I'm am trying to determine a users role using the SP Services library (http://spservices.codeplex.com/), however I am getting responseXML.xml is not an object error.

SPServices + JQuery are both referenced correctly.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser",
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

  alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
         var userPerm = $(xData.responseXML).find("  [nodeName=Permissions]").attr("Value");
  alert("userPerm = " + userPerm);


 }
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hard to tell. What is console.log(xData.responseXML) is telling you? Maybe it's an array. You could try xData.responseXML[0].xml ...

Comment: @NicoO apparantly the code works fine in Firefox but in IE 8.0.7 it produces this error.

Answer (score 1):

Why are trying to use that property of responseXML? If you want access to the raw XML markup, then use the responseText property of xData instead.

I assume that your real goal with the function above (to get the permission) is actually working, correct?

responseXML is a XML Document object that may have different structure depending on browser.

Comment: Paul - responseText returns access denied on /_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx 
in IE but works fine in FF

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery 1.9.1? I that case it's an bug. https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13388

Ajax response object property responseXML will be undefined. While responseText  is containing the raw XML response.
Reference a newer jQuery will populate responseXML correctly.